# SQL Server Having vs Join - performance issues

Tags: sql, sql-server, inner-join, having-clause

I have 2 queries that are almost identical. One executes in just a couple of minutes, the other either times out or takes over 20 minutes. Researched but didn't find online a comparison between Inner join vs Having (only find Where vs Inner Join, or Where vs Having). I would like to understand why one works a lot faster than the other. The 1st query is the one that works OK, the 2nd is the query that is not working properly :

```
SELECT IW.OrderCategory
    , IW.ParkName
    , IW.TurbineNumber
    , IW.UserStatus
    , IW.MaintenancePlan
    , Chk_List.Checklist_Description
    , Chk_List.DateTimeStamp
    , Chk_List.Stamp
    , Chk_List.Man
    , Chk_List.type
    , Chk_List.Joint
    , Chk_List.ToolPos
    , Chk_List.Tech
FROM   ServiceWorkOrders.EDW.SAP_ServiceOrders_IW73 AS IW
      INNER JOIN dbo.vwSQL_Checklist_data_w_item_details AS Chk_List ON IW.TurbineNumber = Chk_List.Turbine_Num
GROUP BY IW.OrderCategory
      , IW.ParkName
      , IW.TurbineNumber
      , IW.UserStatus
      , IW.MaintenancePlan
      , Chk_List.Checklist_Description
      , Chk_List.DateTimeStamp
      , Chk_List.Stamp
      , Chk_List.Man
      , Chk_List.type
      , Chk_List.Joint
      , Chk_List.ToolPos
      , Chk_List.Tech
HAVING(IW.ActualStartDate = MAX(Chk_List.DateStamp));

SELECT IW.OrderCategory
    , IW.ParkName
    , IW.TurbineNumber
    , IW.UserStatus
    , IW.MaintenancePlan
    , Chk_List.Checklist_Description
    , Chk_List.DateTimeStamp
    , Chk_List.Stamp
    , Chk_List.Man
    , Chk_List.type
    , Chk_List.Joint
    , Chk_List.ToolPos
    , Chk_List.Tech
FROM   ServiceWorkOrders.EDW.SAP_ServiceOrders_IW73 AS IW
      INNER JOIN dbo.vwSQL_Checklist_data_w_item_details AS Chk_List ON IW.TurbineNumber = Chk_List.Turbine_Num
                                                           AND IW.ActualStartDate = Chk_List.DateStamp
GROUP BY IW.OrderCategory
      , IW.ParkName
      , IW.TurbineNumber
      , IW.UserStatus
      , IW.MaintenancePlan
      , Chk_List.Checklist_Description
      , Chk_List.DateTimeStamp
      , Chk_List.Stamp
      , Chk_List.Man
      , Chk_List.type
      , Chk_List.Joint
      , Chk_List.ToolPos
      , Chk_List.Tech;
```

Comment: What do Execution Plans show?

Comment: which query is running slower?

Comment: They're performing differently because they're not the same statement. Without sample data I don't know what your end goal is, but changing the join conditons and adding a `having` are going to give the optimizer different bits of information to guess the best plan. If you can attach the execution plans, and/or the table schemas, that might be useful in helping further guide you. the `having` clause must do the aggregate first, and then filter on the max datestamp, whereas the join does it in the opposite order.

Comment: well, for starters the 1st query doesn't have to compare  `IW.ActualStartDate` with every record of `Chk_List.DateStamp` it only takes the `max`. Proper indexing may also help your 2nd query's performance

Comment: Unless you have tens of millions of rows in both tables I would suggest that your first query is way too slow if it is taking 2 minutes. Without some details about the tables we are left guessing.